# Full Cone NAT on Cisco router in Packet Tracer

Tags: cisco, nat, packet-tracer

I am trying to create a network with two subnetworks with private IPs. I need to configure `symmetric NAT` on edge routers within the subnetwork.

Diagram:

[image: Diagram]

I need to configure NAT on `Router0` and `Router2`.

Router0 config -

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 129.0.0.1 255.255.255.252
 ip nat outside
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address 172.16.0.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip nat pool net1 129.0.0.1 129.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.255
ip nat inside source list INSIDE-NET pool net1 overload
ip classless
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 129.0.0.2
```

Router1 config -

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 129.0.0.9 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address 129.0.0.5 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 ip address 129.0.0.2 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
```

Router2 config -

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address 129.0.0.10 255.255.255.252
 ip nat outside
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
router rip
!
ip nat pool net1 129.0.0.10 129.0.0.10 netmask 255.255.255.255
ip nat inside source list INSIDE-NET pool net1 overload
ip classless
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 129.0.0.9
```

Currently, I am able to configure `Dynamic NAT` with a single outside IP overload.

If I try to ping from `192.168.0.2` the translation table on Router2:

[image: translation_table]

If I am not wrong, this is a `symmetric NAT`. Is it possible to configure `full cone NAT` on the Cisco router in Packet Tracer? If so, what should I change, or is there any documentation explaining that?

Thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a good network description or diagram and the router configuration for the router on which you want to configure this. We cannot guess at your configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have added the diagram.

Comment: Please enter the router configurations. The drawing seems to show invalid addressing. We cannot guess how you have configured the routers.

Comment: I have fixed, the subnets in notes, but I don't see any other problem in addressing. The routers are configured, as it's shown in the picture. The interface's IP addresses are in the diagram and routers have default routes configured (also described in the diagram). PCs have an IP address and default GW also described in the diagram.

Comment: Again, please edit the question to include the router configurations. We cannot guess how you have configured the routers, and we will help you fix the configurations, but we will not write the configurations for you. Unless you put in some effort, you are likely to get down votes for which the definition is, "_This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful._" You will see that when hovering the mouse pointer over the down arrow on a question.